# Sass filewatcher for webstorm

Tags: node.js, sass, webstorm

I am trying to use sass in a NodeJS project and this is the library I installed with nodejs

https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-sass

I am using webstorm for this project and I can't get the Sass file watcher to work.

[image]

Even after I save the filewatcher and click "Ok", the filewatcher does not work. When I open the settings to check what's wrong the filewatcher has been unchecked. Here are the filewatcher settings:

[image]

The node-sass module is installed as a global module so the node-sass command works.

Comment: Instead of **just** `node-sass` as a program, you should provide **FULL PATH** to `node-sass.cmd` (or whatever correct executable file name that is). You are making typical mistake on Windows platform: When you running `node-sass` in terminal/console, DOS (cmd.exe) *automatically* converts it to `node-sass.cmd`; but when IDE is creating process for with the same params, the Windows API requires EXACT file name -- it does not do such "conversion" for you.

Comment: I installed it using npm. Not sure where to find the path that node-sass in pointing to.

Comment: Search for `node-sass` on `C:\ ` drive maybe?? It should be in `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming` folder

Comment: I know the folder is there - there is no cmd file inside it however.

Comment: @EternallyCurious, I had the same problem finding the node-sass.cmd. I thought it was node_modules/node-sass/bin folder. It turned out to be in node_modules/.bin folder.

Comment: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-sass.cmd

Comment: @РостиславКирчев Thanks, you saved my life! I was pulling my hair on this one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most definitely path to .cmd is wrong as lena and lazy one suggested. Whenever watcher unchecks in Web/Phpstorm its probably because of invalid path.
If you still have trouble with node-sass you could always go Ruby way.

1. Download and install [Ruby](http://rubyinstaller.org/) for Win,
2. Install Sass via  command prompt with `gem install sass`,
3. In Web/Phpstorm put "Program" path to sass.bat (remember node-sass.cmd?), e.g. `C:\Ruby200\bin\sass.bat`

Answer (score 14):

1. You need to specify a full path to node-sass.cmd in a Program field (as @LazyOne mentioned)
2. Specified arguments won't work with node-sass - they are only suitable for standard SASS compiler. Here is a list of node-sass options:

> ```
> Usage: node C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass
> ```
>
> [options] 
>   `<input.scss>` [`<output.css>`]
>
> ```
> Options:
>   --output-style     CSS output style (nested|expanded|compact|compressed)  [default: "nested"]
>   --source-comments  Include debug info in output (none|normal|map)         [default: "none"]
>   --include-path     Path to look for @import-ed files                      [default: "C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"]
>   --watch, -w        Watch a directory or file
>   --output, -o       Output css file
>   --stdout           Print the resulting CSS to stdout
>   --help, --help     Print usage info
> ```

the simplest setup looks as follows:

```
Program: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-sass.cmd
Arguments: $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Working directory: $FileDir$
Output paths to refresh: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

'Create output from stdout' should be off
```

With such settings the generated .css file will be placed near the original .scss. If you like to put resultant files into a different folder, try playing with `-o` option. Like:

```
Arguments: $FileName$ -o $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
Output paths to refresh: $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
```

Comment: +1 for the details but did you actually make it work? can you detail the paramaters in the Watcher dialog plz? I'm about to switch to ruby because this doesn't work

Comment: Sure:) I've updated the answer accordingly. Do you have any problems setting it up?

Comment: still not working, there is indicator 'Executing SCSS task' and it keep loading for eternity

Comment: same problem here, task never completes.  I am using node-sass.cmd instead of sass-cli.cmd.

Comment: I'd suggest creating a support ticket then

Comment: its working fine for me now, double check that you replace the colons with a forward slash, as I did not at first try and the task would just continue to run, after replacing with forward slash all is well.

Comment: Works for me. I would have marked this as the correct answer as getting Node SASS to work was the original question. For those having trouble my watcher's `programe` is set to `node` and the arguments are `C:\projects\webstorm-testing\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`

Answer (score 7):

First you need install nodejs and then use npm install -g node-sass. After that set following things to webstorm scss filewatcher:

- Program: node-sass.cmd
- Arguments: $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
- Working directory: $FileDir$
- Output paths for refs: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Comment: confirmed in Webstorm 2016.1.1

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been answered, this is for future visitor,

Phpstorm file watcher does not work very well with `node-sass` (tested in Phpstorm 8.0.1 windows)

Instead install `node-sass-cli` and use following setting

[image]

Comment: node-sass-cli has been deprecated in favor of node-sass itself. It now support CLI out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

Phpstorm 8.0.3 Windows 7(x64) node-sass installed globally working example

Another key problem from the original post besides point to .cmd is replacing : with forward slash, node doesn't understand the colon syntax and expects a forward slash instead for the Arguments box.  Found answer from below link

http://www.wonderlandlabs.com/blog/scss_in_webstorm

Note in the above example for windows you need to point to the cmd file ie "path to global npm packages/node-sass.cmd"

Also he has the switches for ruby sass such as --no-cache which won't work with node as lena pointed out, the node-sass switches should work fine, but haven't tested

Here is a working config

[image: node-sass filewatcher]

[image]

Comment: Works in PHPStorm 9.0.0 too.

Answer (score 3):

node-sass requires nothing more than `$FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` *Tested and works in WebStorm 11*

The program parameter needs the full path to the bin/exe though, even when it's globally available. In my case `/usr/local/bin/node-sass`, in your case it will be the path to the `node-sass.cmd`.

[image: SCSS file watcher config]

**node sass cli usage**

```
node-sass [options] <input> [output] cat <input> | node-sass > output
```

**node sass cli parameters**

```
-w, --watch                Watch a directory or file
-r, --recursive            Recursively watch directories or files
-o, --output               Output directory
-x, --omit-source-map-url  Omit source map URL comment from output
-i, --indented-syntax      Treat data from stdin as sass code (versus scss)
-q, --quiet                Suppress log output except on error
-v, --version              Prints version info
--output-style             CSS output style (nested | expanded | compact | compressed)
--indent-type              Indent type for output CSS (space | tab)
--indent-width             Indent width; number of spaces or tabs (maximum value: 10)
--linefeed                 Linefeed style (cr | crlf | lf | lfcr)
--source-comments          Include debug info in output
--source-map               Emit source map
--source-map-contents      Embed include contents in map
--source-map-embed         Embed sourceMappingUrl as data URI
--source-map-root          Base path, will be emitted in source-map as is
--include-path             Path to look for imported files
--follow                   Follow symlinked directories
--precision                The amount of precision allowed in decimal numbers
--importer                 Path to .js file containing custom importer
--functions                Path to .js file containing custom functions
--help                     Print usage info
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers here were very helpful and very close to what I needed. I wanted the app to create the map files and bundle them with the css files. Here are the settings that worked for me. I hope this helps someone else!

- Show console: [Error]
- [x] Immediate file synchronization
- [x] Track only root files
- [ ] Trigger watcher regardless of syntax errors
- File type: Sass
- Scope: Project Files
- Program: /usr/local/bin/node-sass
- Arguments: --source-map true --indented-syntax --output-style compressed $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css
- Working directory: $FileDir$
- Environment Variables:
- Output paths to refresh: $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
- [ ] Create Output file from stdout

Comment: I used to reject installing a whole different language when all I want is covnerting SCSS to CSS. Thus, this is the perfect answer for me. Using PHPStorm 2017.2 the default created by PHPStorm was quite similar to your approach. Changing arguments to your suggestion was only requirement to get it running.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. **The default configuration by IntelliJ doesn't work**.

This one is worked. You can see the different configuration that is marked in yellow.[image]

Comment: Adding the space helped me. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

> *PHP storm version 2018.02*

I was not able to make the filewatcher generate a `css.map` file with the post of Günay,
all the rest of the post works fine for me, so what I use:

**Installation**

Install `node-sass` global: `npm install -g node-sass`

**Settings:**

1. Program `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-sass.cmd`
2. Arguments `--source-map true $FileName$ $FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`
3. Output path to refresh `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map`
4. Working directory `$FileDir$`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I installed `node-sass` through npm (npm install node-sass) to actually transcript `scss` to `css`. The only problem with the config, as in the question, was the **location** of the `node-sass.cmd` file. When installing through npm, you should install the `.cmd` file inside the `node_modules\.bin` folder.

In my case, from where the node-sass file was (`node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass`) to (`node_modules\.bin\node-sass.cmd`).

Also, as per Lena's answer, the output argument should be:

Arguments: `$FileName$ -o $ProjectFileDir$/css/$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css`